# Error in launching a new activity from listview

Tags: android, listview

### Below class I trying to launch a activity on click of a row in the list .... But the emulator closes when i click the row

- employee1 is the new activity i am trying to launch on click of a row
  in a listview
- what changes do i have to make in the below class MainActivity

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static String url="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rhk01nqlyj5gixl/jsonparsing.txt?token_hash=AAHpfauVxJaC9Rkx_5abNtJnPFG04os7TZky1AhOuC5jEw";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Create a JSON parser Instance ----- Used JSON parser from Android
    JSONParser jParser=new JSONParser();

    //Getting JSON string from URL ------ Used JSON Array from Android
    JSONArray json=jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    List<Item> yourData = new ArrayList<Item>();

    try {
        for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject c=json.getJSONObject(i);// Used JSON Object from Android

            //Storing each Json in a string variable
            int AGE=c.getInt("age");
            String NAME=c.getString("name");
            String CITY=c.getString("city");
            String GENDER=c.getString("Gender");
            String BIRTHDATE=c.getString("birthdate");

            yourData.add(new Item(AGE, NAME, CITY, GENDER, BIRTHDATE));

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
    ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow, yourData);
    yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            if(position == 1)
            {
                //code specific to first list item    
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Employee1.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

### I have added about the new activity in the manifest too as below

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testjson.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".employee1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

    </application>
```

**Error.Log::**

```
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.testjson/com.example.testjson.Employee1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.example.testjson.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:69)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-04 13:05:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where is the log? Which error you get?

Comment: Looks like you need `startActivity(myIntent);` instead of `startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);`.

Comment: @Ali `onActivityResult()` should actually be in `MainActivity`, not in `Employee1`.

Comment: I have updated the log .... in my question ..... i am able to display the listview with data in it but when i click to launch the new activity .... i get the error

Comment: Change `android:name=".employee1"` to `android:name="com.example.testjson.Employee1"` in your manifest.

Comment: employee1 should be same case as your Manifest file (Employee1)

Comment: Even.though i update .... startActivity(myIntent); .... still issue remains

Comment: @ Mohamed_AbdAllah & @ Vikram....... Your solution worked for me ..... There was a wrong mentioning of file name in manifest .... thanks